# Command line sorcerery

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, command

I have a directory full of .xls files that I want to convert to .csv. I'm using xls2csv. This command only prints out the csv to the screen so I believe you have to do xls2csv (xls file) > (new file).csv. So for this I need to write a loop.

```
for f in `ls`; do xls2csv > `rev $f` | cut -d "." | rev | echo ".csv"
```

That's what I have so far and it doesn't work. I'm just hoping you can understand exactly what I want to do by the above example.

Comment: What about globbing? Something like xls2csv 'my/path/*.xls' The question is, how to output each file?

Comment: `for f in \`ls\`` looks really ugly, and breaks completely if `ls` is aliased to `ls -l` or something similar. `for f in *.xls` is much better.

Answer (score 9):

```
for f in *.xls; do
  basename="${f%.xls}"
  csvname="$basename.csv"
  xls2csv "$f" > "$csvname"
done
```

[update] fixed the typo, so that `$basename` is actually used. Thanks.

Comment: What does basename="${f%.xls}" accomplish?

Comment: @grok12, it takes the value of $f and removes the suffix ".xls". See [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual.

Comment: Good point with the ${f% syntax. Line 3 should be csvnmane="$basename.csv", I assume?

Comment: @thiton: Yes, that's what I was getting at.  basename is not used.  Although if Glenn Jackman doesn't agree then I'm worried that I'm wrong.

Comment: This doesn't work. Output being "bash: : No such file or directory". And I see that you're assigning a value to $basename and then not using the variable?

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel has a feature for this: {.} which is the original string but with the .extension removed:

```
ls | parallel xls2csv {} ">" {.}.csv
```

Plus you get the added bonus that xls2csv will be run in parallel if you have multiple CPUs. It also deals correctly with file names like:

```
My Brother's 12" records.xls
```

To learn more watch the intro video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *; do
    c=`echo $f | sed 's/.xls$/.csv/'`
    xls2csv $f >$c
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `basename` command, using the `-s` switch.

(I think you're using `rev` to reverse the filename - is that right? I removed it.)

```
for f in `ls`; do
     xls2csv $f > `basename -s xls $f`csv;
done
```

Try that. I don't know if xls2csv is destructive (like sed), so back up your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
type=".csv";
for f in `ls -1`;
do
file=`echo $f|cut -d '.' -f1`
file=${file}${type}
`xls2csv $f > $file`
done
```

Comment: What if the filename contains 2 dots?

Comment: that's likely wouldn't be the case ... even it's it would be very rare ... yup haven't taken care about that possibility